# C# EF update related entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to update references between 2 entities. Sadly my update methods only work on simple fields, but not on whole entities.

In my `DbContext` I have the update method:

```
public void UpdateProject(Project e)
{
    this.projects.Attach(e);
    this.employees.Attach(e.ProjectLeader); //added later
    this.Entry<Project>(e).State = EntityState.Modified;
    this.Entry<Employee>(e.ProjectLeader).State = EntityState.Modified; //added later
    this.SaveChanges();
}
```

The ones I added later were added because of different suggestions throughout the web.

I have following (simplified) classes:

```
public class Employee
{
    [DataMember]
    public int? ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual Project LeaderOfProject { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Project
{
    [DataMember]
    public int? ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public String Titel { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Employee ProjectLeader { get; set; }
}
```

This relationship is defined in my `OnModelCreate` method like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

    modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
                .HasOptional<Project>(e => e.LeaderOfProject)
                .WithOptionalPrincipal(p => p.ProjectLeader)
                .Map(m => m.MapKey("ProjectLeader"));
}
```

With the update method shown above I am able to update the `Titel` field, but I can't assign any `Employee` as new `ProjectLeader` (no error, but no update as well).

What do I need to change to update/change the related entities?

Any help is really appreciated.

---

I also tried with

```
this.Entry(e).CurrentValues.SetValues(e);
this.Entry(e.ProjectLeader).CurrentValues.SetValues(e.ProjectLeader);
```

but no success.

Method to retrieve objects from EF:

```
public Project FindProjectById(int id)
{
    Project Result = this.projects
        .Include(x => x.ProjectLeader)
        .Include(x => x.EmployeesWorkingOnProject)
        .Include(x => x.ProjectSteps)
        .SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == id);
    return Result;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code showing how you get the object from EF?

Comment: @RyanS I added the method. `ProjectLeader` is going to be one of the `Employee` from `EmployeesWorkingOnProject`

Comment: Are you sure that the issue is not related to the read process? You did not marked as virtual ProjectLeader. Hibernate raise an error while EF simply disable lazy load.

Comment: @bubi `ProjectLeader` is not just a navigational property. I think that StevePy's answer is what I was looking for even if it feels dirty

Comment: Navigation properties have a different behaviour, I forgot about that. You can find several issues around. Probably another good solution is to add the foreign key column as property (EF works better if you insert it).

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can do this by attaching the modified entity to the context vs. loading the original entities, disassociating the reference between them, then associating the new references.

Given a record that had Employee A <-> Project A
you change the detached entities so that Employee B <-> Project A.

Project A's Employee might be pointing at B, but according to the context, Employee A's still pointing at Project A. Employee is the principal.

Bidirectional references are almost always a pain. :)

What you'll likely need to do would be something like:

```
public void UpdateProject(Project e)
{
    var project = this.projects.Find(e.ProjectId);
    project.ProjectLeader.LeaderOfProject = null; // De-associate Employee A's project.
    //Copy values from e to project.
    project.StartDate = e.StartDate; // May be able to use CopyValues against Entity(project)... Would need to test. :)

    var employee = this.employees.Attach(e.ProjectLeader); // Attach employee B to this context.
    project.ProjectLeader = employee; // Associate Employee B to project, and project to employee B.
    employee.LeaderOfProject = project;
    this.SaveChanges();
}
```

Caveat: I'm not 100% sure this will work, but hopefully it gives you some ideas to narrow down how to re-associate the entities.

Comment: Ahh okay that is how it should be roughly done. I am used to Hibernate from Java where you can just assign a new reference and call the update method. I made a little hack with plain SQL to set the reference in the table and then set `e.ProjectLeader = null;` and update afterwards. Not nice but working, still thank you very much for your effort